# How to get two values altogether on object clicked from QWebEngineView in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, jinja2, qwebengineview

I have 2 files : one is `MAIN.py` and other is `xpath_from_element.js`. I used `QWebEngineWidgets` to display the web-page on the app, And linked both `.py` and `.js` to get `TagNames`/`XPATH` from the website when one clicks on it. I am currently getting `tagNames` of the elements.

What if i have to get `tagNames` and `classNames` both at once. For example : clicking on a button gives me both `tagName` and `className` at once. Because currently it's giving me only one. I have tried doing that, but it always gives me error, so i have posted the original fine running code and not my error producing code cause i don't know how to do that and was unable to find any resources to do so.

**Here is Main.py :**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel, QtGui
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QSizeGrip, QGridLayout, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from jinja2 import Template
import sqlite3
import time
from D_scraper import to_do
import D_scraper2

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Crawl_jar\test.db')

try:
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE Classes (id VARCHAR(30));""")
    conn.commit()
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE urls (id VARCHAR(30));""")
    conn.commit()
except:
    pass

def insert_url_to_sql(the_url):
    conn.execute(f"""INSERT INTO urls VALUES ("{the_url}");""")
    conn.commit()

class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.setMinimumSize(320, 240)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(15,6)
        self.btn.setFixedSize(80, 30)
        self.btn.setText("Excecute")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.run_myscript)

        self.text_url = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text_url.move(100, 6)
        self.text_url.setFixedSize(140, 30)

        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.move(250,6)
        self.btn2.setFixedSize(80, 30)
        self.btn2.setText("Load")
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.load_the_url)

        self.cb = QComboBox(self)
        self.cb.addItem("1")
        self.cb.addItem("2")
        self.cb.addItems(["3", "4", "5"])
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
        self.cb.move(350, 7)
        self.cb.setFixedSize(35, 28)
        self.cb.show()

        self.show()

    def run_myscript(self):
        if self.combo_value == "3":
            window.hide()
            app.quit()
            D_scraper2.to_do()
        else:
            print("Error no option selected!")

        print("Select a value...")

    def selectionchange(self):
        print ("Items in the list are :")
        self.combo_value = self.cb.currentText()
        print (self.combo_value)

    # Show widget
    def load_the_url(self):
        self.url_string = self.text_url.text()
        self.u1 = self.url_string.replace('(','')
        self.u2 = self.u1.replace(')','')
        self.u3 = self.u2.replace("'",'')
        self.u4 = self.u3.replace(",",'')
        self.u5 = self.u4.replace("True",'')
        self.u6 = self.u5.replace(" ",'')
        self.url = self.u6
        print(self.u6)

        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        self.view.move(10, 80)
        self.view.setFixedSize(1345, 500)

        classname_helper = Helper("classname_helper")
        classname_helper.classClicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.page = WebEnginePage()
        self.page.add_object(classname_helper)
        self.view.setPage(self.page)
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.url))
        print(str(self.url))
        self.view.show()

    def on_clicked(self, name):
        print(name)
        conn.execute(f"""INSERT INTO Classes VALUES ("{name}");""")
        conn.commit()
        insert_url_to_sql(self.url)

class Element(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Element, self).__init__(parent)
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def script(self):
        return ""

class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebEnginePage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        self._objects = []
        self._scripts = []

    def add_object(self, obj):
        self._objects.append(obj)

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def onLoadFinished(self, ok):
        print("Finished loading: ", ok)
        if ok:
            self.load_qwebchannel()
            self.add_objects()

    def load_qwebchannel(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile(":/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js")
        if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            content = file.readAll()
            file.close()
            self.runJavaScript(content.data().decode())
        if self.webChannel() is None:
            channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
            self.setWebChannel(channel)

    def add_objects(self):
        if self.webChannel() is not None:
            objects = {obj.name: obj for obj in self._objects}
            self.webChannel().registerObjects(objects)
            _script = """
            {% for obj in objects %}
            var {{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            {% for obj in objects %}
                {{obj}} = channel.objects.{{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            }); 
            """
            self.runJavaScript(Template(_script).render(objects=objects.keys()))
            for obj in self._objects:
                if isinstance(obj, Element):
                    self.runJavaScript(obj.script())

class Helper(Element):
    classClicked = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def script(self):
        js = """
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            e.preventDefault()
            {{name}}.objectClicked(target.tagName);
        }, false);"""
        return Template(js).render(name=self.name)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def objectClicked(self, className):
        if className:
            self.classClicked.emit(className)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**The .JS File :** (to get the classNames/tagNames when clicked)

```
Elements = {};
Elements.DOMPath = {};

/**
 * @param {!Node} node
 * @param {boolean=} optimized
 * @return {string}
 */
Elements.DOMPath.xPath = function (node, optimized) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        return '/';
    }

    const steps = [];
    let contextNode = node;
    while (contextNode) {
        const step = Elements.DOMPath._xPathValue(contextNode, optimized);
        if (!step) {
            break;
        }  // Error - bail out early.
        steps.push(step);
        if (step.optimized) {
            break;
        }
        contextNode = contextNode.parentNode;
    }

    steps.reverse();
    return (steps.length && steps[0].optimized ? '' : '/') + steps.join('/');
};

/**
 * @param {!Node} node
 * @param {boolean=} optimized
 * @return {?Elements.DOMPath.Step}
 */
Elements.DOMPath._xPathValue = function (node, optimized) {
    let ownValue;
    const ownIndex = Elements.DOMPath._xPathIndex(node);
    if (ownIndex === -1) {
        return null;
    }  // Error.

    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            if (optimized && node.getAttribute('id')) {
                return new Elements.DOMPath.Step('//*[@id="' + node.getAttribute('id') + '"]', true);
            }
            ownValue = node.localName;
            break;
        case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
            ownValue = '@' + node.nodeName;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            ownValue = 'text()';
            break;
        case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:
            ownValue = 'processing-instruction()';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            ownValue = 'comment()';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
            ownValue = '';
            break;
        default:
            ownValue = '';
            break;
    }

    if (ownIndex > 0) {
        ownValue += '[' + ownIndex + ']';
    }

    return new Elements.DOMPath.Step(ownValue, node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE);
};

/**
 * @param {!Node} node
 * @return {number}
 */
Elements.DOMPath._xPathIndex = function (node) {
    // Returns -1 in case of error, 0 if no siblings matching the same expression,
    // <XPath index among the same expression-matching sibling nodes> otherwise.
    function areNodesSimilar(left, right) {
        if (left === right) {
            return true;
        }

        if (left.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && right.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return left.localName === right.localName;
        }

        if (left.nodeType === right.nodeType) {
            return true;
        }

        // XPath treats CDATA as text nodes.
        const leftType = left.nodeType === Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ? Node.TEXT_NODE : left.nodeType;
        const rightType = right.nodeType === Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ? Node.TEXT_NODE : right.nodeType;
        return leftType === rightType;
    }

    const siblings = node.parentNode ? node.parentNode.children : null;
    if (!siblings) {
        return 0;
    }  // Root node - no siblings.
    let hasSameNamedElements;
    for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; ++i) {
        if (areNodesSimilar(node, siblings[i]) && siblings[i] !== node) {
            hasSameNamedElements = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasSameNamedElements) {
        return 0;
    }
    let ownIndex = 1;  // XPath indices start with 1.
    for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; ++i) {
        if (areNodesSimilar(node, siblings[i])) {
            if (siblings[i] === node) {
                return ownIndex;
            }
            ++ownIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;  // An error occurred: |node| not found in parent's children.
};

/**
 * @unrestricted
 */
Elements.DOMPath.Step = class {
    /**
     * @param {string} value
     * @param {boolean} optimized
     */
    constructor(value, optimized) {
        this.value = value;
        this.optimized = optimized || false;
    }

    /**
     * @override
     * @return {string}
     */
    toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
};
```

Also please do mention how you solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is similar to my other answers that I have provided, but you may not understand it because you probably have not analyzed it in detail.

The logic is:

- Create a class that inherits from Element and override the script method that implements the logic of the program (in this case load the script xpath_from_element.js, implement the algorithm of obtaining the clicked element, obtain the necessary attributes and send them to a slot) .
- Create a signal with the necessary number of arguments (in this case the xpath and tagName)
- Create a slot where the information is received and emit the signal.

With the above I hope you understand the simple logic of my implementation.

```py
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel

from jinja2 import Template


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Element(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Element, self).__init__(parent)
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def script(self):
        return ""


class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebEnginePage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        self._objects = []
        self._scripts = []

    def add_object(self, obj):
        self._objects.append(obj)

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def onLoadFinished(self, ok):
        print("Finished loading: ", ok)
        if ok:
            self.load_qwebchannel()
            self.add_objects()

    def load_qwebchannel(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile(":/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js")
        if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            content = file.readAll()
            file.close()
            self.runJavaScript(content.data().decode())
        if self.webChannel() is None:
            channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
            self.setWebChannel(channel)

    def add_objects(self):
        if self.webChannel() is not None:
            objects = {obj.name: obj for obj in self._objects}
            self.webChannel().registerObjects(objects)
            _script = """
            {% for obj in objects %}
            var {{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            {% for obj in objects %}
                {{obj}} = channel.objects.{{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            }); 
            """
            self.runJavaScript(Template(_script).render(objects=objects.keys()))
            for obj in self._objects:
                if isinstance(obj, Element):
                    self.runJavaScript(obj.script())


class Helper(Element):
    elementClicked = QtCore.Signal(str, str)

    def script(self):
        js = ""
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "xpath_from_element.js"))
        if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            content = file.readAll()
            file.close()
            js = content.data().decode()

        js += """
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            var xpath = Elements.DOMPath.xPath(target, false); 
            var tagName = target.tagName;
            {{name}}.received_data(xpath, tagName);
        }, false);"""
        return Template(js).render(name=self.name)

    @QtCore.Slot(str, str)
    def received_data(self, xpath, tagName):
        self.elementClicked.emit(xpath, tagName)


class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.setMinimumSize(320, 240)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.execute_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Execute"))
        self.load_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Load"))
        self.url_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

        self.page = WebEnginePage(self)
        self.view.setPage(self.page)

        classname_helper = Helper("classname_helper")
        classname_helper.elementClicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.page.add_object(classname_helper)

        gridlayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.execute_btn, 0, 0)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.url_le, 0, 1)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.load_btn, 0, 2)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.cb, 0, 3)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 4, 0)

        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

        self.execute_btn.clicked.connect(self.run_myscript)
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load_the_url)
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)

    def run_myscript(self):
        pass

    def selectionchange(self):
        print("Items in the list are :")
        self.combo_value = self.cb.currentText()
        print(self.combo_value)

    def load_the_url(self):
        text = self.url_le.text()
        for letter in ("(", ")", "'", ",", "True", " "):
            text = text.replace(letter, "")
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl(text))

    def on_clicked(self, xpath, tagName):
        print("on_clicked:", xpath, tagName)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks  @eyllanesc for answering. Now I understand this very clearly. But with an exception. I didn't understand writing `elements.DOMPath.xPath(target, false);` for xPath. We didn't use that for tagName. For that you used just `target.tagName` .But why for XPATH ?

Comment: Also i noticed that the webpage loads more quickly than before. Is it because you corrected something or my internet connection is good enough today? @eyllanesc